# how to know that the message is a reply in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Since there is no possibility to get email header from MS Graph API i want to manage references/in-reply-to in a different way. How can I know that the mail I got is the reply? I was trying to do it using conversationId but every my reply had new conversationId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this information isn't exposed. There is however a feature request in the [UserVoice for exposing headers](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/18159700-allow-microsoft-graph-api-to-return-mail-headers).

Answer (score 1):

Look into conversationIndex (something like conversationId + time stamps of reply history for this email)

From my understanding, a mail is a reply to another mail iff its conversationIndex equals the conversationIndex of the other mail concatenated with its own time stamp.